# groupby a column and find the count of this column and other column and find the quotient of the two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The df I am working with is:

| rank | response |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| null | 1 |

my desired output:

| rank | response_count | count_of_the_rank | response_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 0.66 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| null | 1 | 1 | 1 |

response rate is calculated as response_count/count_of_the_rank

I want to have a function that will produce this data frame and store in a csv given:

1. df
2. columne

this is my attempt without a function:
it works but the quotient is calculated outside, is it possible to do it inside of the agg?
also no csv

```
rank_df = df.groupby(['rank']).agg(
    count_of_the_rank=('rank', 'count'),
    response_count=('response', 'sum'))
rank_df['group_target_rate'] = rank_df['response_count']/rank_df['count_of_the_rank']
```

this is trying with a function but it doesnt work:

```
def target_rate_analysis(df, column):
    new_df = df.groupby([column]).agg(
        response_count=('response', 'sum'),
        'count_of_the' + column=(column, 'count'),
        response_count=('response', 'mean'))
    return new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and then [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) (for the `response_rate` you can use `"mean"`):

```
df_out = df.groupby("rank", as_index=False).agg(
    response_count=("response", "sum"),
    count_of_the_rank=("response", "size"),
    response_rate=("response", "mean"),
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   rank  response_count  count_of_the_rank  response_rate
0     1               1                  2       0.500000
1     2               2                  3       0.666667
2     3               0                  1       0.000000
```

---

EDIT: As a function:

```
def analysis(df, column):
    return df.groupby("rank", as_index=False).agg(
        **{
            "{}_count".format(column): (column, "sum"),
            "{}_count_of_the_rank".format(column): (column, "size"),
            "{}_rate".format(column): (column, "mean"),
        }
    )


print(analysis(df, "response"))
```

Prints:

```
   rank  response_count  response_count_of_the_rank  response_rate
0     1               1                           2       0.500000
1     2               2                           3       0.666667
2     3               0                           1       0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you! is it possible to make this into a function? like if i pass a list of columns and for each individual columns, i will generate a csv for this column

Comment: I figured out with your edit! thank you! :)

Comment: hi, what if we have null as a category? how do we get the count of nulls as a group? I see now it shows as 0 for volume of response count